# Can I use cmake that bundled in CLion in my terminal?

Tags: cmake, terminal, clion

So I have CLion IDE and I wonder if I can use Cmake that my CLion use straightly from terminal. Because the system tells me that cmake isn't installed so there is no cmake in /usr/bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, all you need to do is find the `absolute path` to the CMake binary bundled with your CLion installation.

```bash
# This can help you find the binary if you don't know where it is
# Substitute <dir> for where you want to search on the system
$ find <dir> -executable -type f -name cmake

# It will give you can output like this
/usr/foobar/baz/clion/cmake/3.24.0/bin/cmake
```

Then you'll just need to add CMake to your path.

Here is some bash code that does that:

```bash
PATH="/usr/foobar/baz/clion/cmake/3.24.0/bin:$PATH"

export PATH
```

Place the above code in your `.bash_aliases` or your `.bashrc` whichever approach you prefer. So that the `PATH` is persistently modified in your terminal sessions.

Then reload `.bashrc`

```bash
$> source .bashrc
```

Then you'll know you succeeded when you get a result like this:

```bash
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.24.0

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

Comment: If you installed CLion using the JetBrains toolbox, you probably want to start with `~/.local/share/JetBrains/` as the base path, and will end up with something like `./Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/232.8660.186/bin/cmake/linux/x64/bin/cmake`